# Can controls rendered within a wpf Viewport3D using a VisualBrush fire their specific events?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, 3d, visualbrush

I'm trying to render a Button on a GeometryModel3D by using a VisualBrush. Is there a way I can handle the button's click event directly? (or is it that the VisualBrush only renders the image of a button and I am supposed to use the VisualTree in order to check if the button was pressed? )

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A brush is just a brush - you will not get events or behaviors associated with the source element of the VisualBrush. If your goal is to render interactive 2D controls on a 3D mesh then take a look at the [Viewport2DVisual3D class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.viewport2dvisual3d.aspx).